# XSLT - Base64 Decoding

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to decode the base64 encoded value to a string in XSLT.

This is the encoded value that i will get as XML.

```
Z3VpZD11cm46dG9waWM6RjlDMkMyNkFFNERCNDY2OThFRjZEMTdDOUI5RTlFNEI7cGFyZW50Z3VpZD11cm46dG9waWM6MEQxNDQxODMxQjRDNEM2OEEzMURGMzVBMTA0NjUyOTY
```

If so please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commercial versions of the Saxon 9.5 XSLT 2.0 processor provide an extension function `saxon:base64Binary-to-string`,

The documentation for it can be found [here](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/base64Binary-to-string)
.

For example:

```
saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary("Z3VpZD11cm46dG9waWM6RjlDMkMyNkFFNERCNDY2OThFRjZEMTdDOUI5RTlFNEI7cGFyZW50Z3VpZD11cm46dG9waWM6MEQxNDQxODMxQjRDNEM2OEEzMURGMzVBMTA0NjUyOTY"), "UTF8")
```

You will need to adjust the second parameter with the encoding used.